# Get selected value from drop-down and display the value in textbox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to get selected value from drop-down and display the value in textbox in SharePoint standard list form.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you find any of the answer below helpful, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using jQuery easily.

to get selected data you can use

`$("#dropdownid option:selected").text();`

And to populate text box

`$("#textboxid").val("ValueYouWantToAssign")`

You have to include jquery reference for using this. If using sharepoint 2013 it is already included.

For more info: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can get the value from drop-down and display it in text-box:

//This gets selected value from drop-down control:

```
var ddl_value = $("#drop-downID option:selected").text();
```

//This updates and displays value from drop-down in text-box:

```
$("#textboxid").val(ddl_value);
```

But remember you cannot edit the default list forms. To add this code you should create a custom list form and make that form as the default form (edit/new). This can be achieved in SharePoint Designer.